# Toast msg displaying 2nd item when selected the 1st one for spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-toast

NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.wastewarriorsnew;


public class NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter extends Activity implements SpinnerAdapter, ListAdapter {
    protected static final int EXTRA = 1;
    protected SpinnerAdapter adapter;
    protected Context context;
    protected int nothingSelectedLayout;
    protected int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
    protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
              SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
              int nothingSelectedLayout, Context context) {

                this(spinnerAdapter, nothingSelectedLayout, -1, context);
            }


            public NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter,
                    int nothingSelectedLayout, int nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, Context context) {
                this.adapter = spinnerAdapter;
                this.context = context;
                this.nothingSelectedLayout = nothingSelectedLayout;
                this.nothingSelectedDropdownLayout = nothingSelectedDropdownLayout;
                layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nothing_selected_spinner_adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater()
                .inflate(R.menu.nothing_selected_spinner_adapter, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int count = adapter.getCount();
            return count == 0 ? 0 : count + EXTRA;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position == 0 ? null : adapter.getItem(position - EXTRA);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return position >= EXTRA ? adapter.getItemId(position - EXTRA) : position - EXTRA;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // This provides the View for the Selected Item in the Spinner, not
        // the dropdown (unless dropdownView is not set).
        if (position == 0) {
            return getNothingSelectedView(parent);
        }
        return adapter.getView(position - EXTRA, null, parent); // Could re-use
                                                 // the convertView if possible.

    }

    protected View getNothingSelectedView(ViewGroup parent) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedLayout, parent, false);
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return adapter.hasStableIds();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return adapter.isEmpty();
         }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position != 0; // Don't allow the 'nothing selected'
        // item to be picked.
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Android BUG! http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17128 -
        // Spinner does not support multiple view types
        if (position == 0) {
            return nothingSelectedDropdownLayout == -1 ?
              new View(context) :
              getNothingSelectedDropdownView(parent);
        }

        // Could re-use the convertView if possible, use setTag...
        return adapter.getDropDownView(position - EXTRA, null, parent);
    }
     protected View getNothingSelectedDropdownView(ViewGroup parent) {
            return layoutInflater.inflate(nothingSelectedDropdownLayout, parent, false);
        }

}
```

This code i have taken it from here itself.
The problem I am facing is,as soon as the main activity loads,there are 2 toast msgs being displayed of the first item.
And when I'm selecting first element,the toast msg is displaying the 2nd element.Some problem in the index is occurring.
Plz help.

Thankss.

Mainactivity.java

```
String[] countries = {"Dehradun","Solapur","Pune","Mumbai"};

String[] city = {"Dehradun","Solapur","Pune","Mumbai"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Spinner element
    final  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final  Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

      ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
      dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

      spinner.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(dataAdapter,
             R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,this));
              // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional

      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

      ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, city);
      dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

   spinner1.setAdapter(
      new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
              dataAdapter1,
              R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
              // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional
            this));
     spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // On selecting a spinner item
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)parent;
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)parent;

    if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected: " +countries[position] , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(spinner1.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected: " + city[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: What purpose does EXTRA have? Try setting protected static final int EXTRA = 0;

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you click on the first spinner you see the second spinner element? Or if you click on the first element of the spinner you see the second element of the first spinner?

Comment: let me tell u about the first spinner.when i click first element of first spinner,it displays toast msg of second element of first spinner .

Comment: when i did,EXTRA=0,the first element of my first spinner is dissappered,and the toast msg is also apperaing twice for the first element of first spinner,on form load